# Integrable almost complex structure conjugated by diffeomorphism

Tags: complex-geometry, almost-complex

Let $M$ be a smooth manifold and $J$ be an integrable almost complex structure on $M$. Let $f: M\to M$ be a diffeomorphism with $f_{*}:TM\to TM$ its tangent map. Then it is easy to see that $f_{*}Jf_{*}^{-1}$ is a new almost complex structure.

Question: Is $f_{*}Jf_{*}^{-1}$ an integrable almost complex structure on $M$?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As $f$ is a diffeomorphism, $f_* : \mathfrak{X}(M) \to \mathfrak{X}(M)$ is an isomorphism of vector spaces, and as $f_*[X_1, X_2] = [f_*X_1, f_*X_2]$, it is also an isomorphism of Lie algebras; the same is true for $f_*^{-1}$.

Let $Y_1, Y_2 \in \mathfrak{X}(M)$. As $f_*$ is an isomorphism, there are $X_1, X_2 \in \mathfrak{X}(M)$ such that $f_*X_i = Y_i$ (and hence $f_*^{-1}Y_i = X_i$).

Now we have

\begin{align*}
&N_{f_*Jf_*^{-1}}(Y_1, Y_2)\\ 
=&\ N_{f_*Jf_*^{-1}}(f_*X_1, f_*X_2)\\
=&\ [f_*X_1, f_*X_2] + f_*Jf_*^{-1}([f_*Jf_*^{-1}f_*X_1, f_*X_2] + [f_*X_1, f_*Jf_*^{-1}f_*X_2])\\ 
&- [f_*Jf_*^{-1}f_*X_1, f_*Jf_*^{-1}f_*X_2]\\
=&\ [f_*X_1, f_*X_2] + f_*Jf_*^{-1}([f_*JX_1, f_*X_2] + [f_*X_1, f_*JX_2]) - [f_*JX_1, f_*JX_2]\\
=&\ f_*[X_1, X_2] + f_*Jf_*^{-1}(f_*[JX_1, X_2] + f_*[X_1, JX_2]) - f_*[JX_1, JX_2]\\
=&\ f_*[X_1, X_2] + f_*Jf_*^{-1}f_*([JX_1, X_2] + [X_1, JX_2]) - f_*[JX_1, JX_2]\\
=&\ f_*[X_1, X_2] + f_*J([JX_1, X_2] + [X_1, JX_2]) - f_*[JX_1, JX_2]\\
=&\ f_*\left\{[X_1, X_2] + J([JX_1, X_2] + [X_1, JX_2]) - [JX_1, JX_2]\right\}\\
=&\ f_*N_J(X_1, X_2)\\
=&\ f_*N_J(f_*^{-1}Y_1, f_*^{-1}Y_2).
\end{align*}

So $f_*Jf_*^{-1}$ is integrable if and only if $J$ is integrable.

Comment: Thank you for the nice answer!

Comment: I have one more question. It follows from your argument that if $J$  is integrable, then $f: (M,J)\to (M,f_*Jf_*^{-1})$ is a biholomorphic map of complex manifolds since it commute the almost complex structures. But not all diffeomorphisms of complex manifolds are biholomorphic map. Where is the problem here?

Comment: The problem is that $f : (M, J) \to (M, J)$ is not a biholomorphism.

Comment: Do you mean $J$ and $f_*Jf_*^{-1}$ determine different complex structures?

Comment: Yes, they can be different (this happens precisely when $f : (M, J) \to (M, J)$ is not a biholomorphism).

Comment: But we already know that $f: (M,J)\to (M,f_*Jf_*^{-1})$ is a biholomorphic map of complex manifolds, so they are the same as complex manifolds?

Comment: That's true, but that does not mean $J = f_*Jf_*^{-1}$.

Answer (score 1):

Note the following two interesting phenomena:

1.$f: (M,J)\to (M,f_*Jf_*^{-1})$ is a biholomorphic map but $f : (M, J) \to (M, J)$ may be not a biholomorphic map.

2.$Id: (M,J)\to (M,f_*Jf_*^{-1})$ may be not a biholomorphic map but $Id : (M, J) \to (M, J)$ is a biholomorphic map.

The point is that although $(M,J)$ is isomorphic to $(M,f_*Jf_*^{-1})$, but they are not exactly the same complex manifolds. In other words, they have isomorphic but different complex structures.